# Tile more than 9 images with Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, image, tiles

I want to draw 15 images in `drawRect:` but the biggest I could find was `NSDrawNinePartImage()` I want 4 corners, top/bottom fill, and 3 rows between them (two side fills and a center fill)

What is recommended here? NinePart + 2 * ThreePart? Or something else?

Comment: I think you should add some more detail to this question. It's hard to know how to answer it without knowing what you're trying to draw.

Comment: Sorry for not adding some details. I added them now.

Answer (score 1):

`NSDrawNinePartImage` is for drawing a single thing that's divided into nine aligned sections like a tic-tac-toe/noughts-and-crosses board.

The primary use case for that is a rounded-rectangle UI element, such as a button. You'd have four fixed-size corners, four uniaxially-stretchable sides, and one biaxially-stretchable center.

That doesn't fit with what you're describing. Three center columns?

If the two extra columns should be fixed in horizontal size, then put each end's images together into a single image per corner and per side. Then use `NSDrawNinePartImage` as normal.

If the two extra columns are part of the center column and so should be horizontally stretchable, then I suggest that you use `NSDrawThreePartImage` from inside an NSCustomImageRep subclass and use an instance of that subclass for each of three center-column part images. Then use `NSDrawNinePartImage` as normal.

(Substitute “rows” for “columns” and “vertically” for “horizontally” in the previous three paragraphs if you want.)

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at what NSCustomImageRep gives me.

Comment: It doesn't give you anything. It's exactly what it says: A *custom* image rep. You subclass it and then you implement it.